# Are special characters in the body of a commit message allowed?

Tags: git, special-characters, commit-message

I used special characters like "" and <> or ' in the body of my commit message, is this allowed or should i use text only ?

I didnt find a real answear, and i dont want to f up my github history, so an answear would really help me out!

Comment: They are definitely fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only disallowed character in a git commit message is the NUL byte. Any other characters from any encoding are fine.

Comment: Interestingly enough this almost entirely forbids the use of UTF-16 ;-) Except if avoid all ASCII-range characters (including space and newline).