# Is the colon (:) allowed in GitHub commit messages?

Tags: git, github

I'm curious about whether it's acceptable to use the colon (:) symbol in GitHub commit messages and whether there are any potential drawbacks to doing so.

Comment: No technical reason for why it wouldn't be. Even encouraged in many commit styles, e.g. https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/, not that I would think the Conventional Commits style is particularly useful though.

Comment: Do you have a reason to expect it to not be acceptable (for git generally or by github specifically)? If so, please provide that reason as well. This way answers could be more useful (for you and future readers).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are special characters in the body of a commit message allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74476235/are-special-characters-in-the-body-of-a-commit-message-allowed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use a colon as well as any other special characters. GitHub doesn't restrict it in commit messages.